# how to update django databsae from html?

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to only update the brand. So I want to see if I can get the post from the input. 
print(request.POST.get('brand')) didn't print anything, but I can get print(request.POST.get('url')). Does anyone know why?
Here is my base.html code.

```
<form action="{% url 'script' %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group w-75">
        <input type="text" name="url" id="url" class="form-control">
    </br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">submit</button>
</div>
</br>

{% if alldata %}


<table class="table table-striped table-sm" id="">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Asin</th>
            <th>Rank</th>
            <th>Brand</th>
            <th>CPU</th>
            <th>Update</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for data in alldata %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ data.price }}</td>
            <td> <a href="{{ data.link }}">{{ data.asin }}</a> </td>
            <td>{{ data.rank }}</td>

            <td>    
                <div>
                {{ data.brand }} <input type="text" name="brand" id="brand" value="{{data.brand}}">
                <button type="submit">Update</button>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>cpu</td>
            <td><button type="submit">Update</button></td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}

    </tbody>
</table>

{% endif %}

</form>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `print(request.POST.getlist('brand'))`?

Comment: Show your function. I need to see what `alldata` is, and any other mistakes you may have made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check All data in request.POST:

```
print(request.POST)
```

to print only one 'field'

```
print(request.POST['field'])
```